# New Facebook SDK FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication

I've been trying to develop iOS app using Facebook and I'm new. So I've been trying to make

a login with Facebook, followed a tutorial on Facebook and try to implement it.

But I've encountered, `[FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions]` not found. When I run the

app, it will force close and say that error. When build the project, it will show warning

yellow exclamation that `sessionOpenWithPermission` is not found in `FBSession`

The tutorial outdated? If it is, then what is the new code for the new Facebook SDK for

sessionOpenWithPermission ?

Comment: I think this is valid- I am having the same issue with the Facebook example.

Comment: This is clearly a documentation mismatch issue. I suggest to look at the "Scrumptious" example app that ships with the SDK for up to date documentation.

Comment: there is a mismatch in the docs tutorial and the sample. You should use       `- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This Code**

```
 account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType]; 


    appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    chk=appDelegate.chk_login;

    if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        // create a fresh session object
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
            // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
            [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState status,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                // we recurse here, in order to update buttons and labels

            }];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since `FBSession` has `activeSession` static public variable, you don't have to save the session in app delegate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code helps you, put it in your `AppDelegate.m` class

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            self.loggedinVCController = [[LoggedinVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoggedinVC" bundle:nil];
            self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.loggedinVCController];
            self.window.rootViewControlle`enter code here`r = self.navController;

        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // Once the user has logged in, we want them to
            // be looking at the root view.
            [self.navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

            self.viewController = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil];
            self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
- (void)openSession
{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 Login Tutorial Issue with FBSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925987/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-login-tutorial-issue-with-fbsession)

```
//REPLACE
[FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions:nil
                    completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                    }];

//WITH
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:nil
                               allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                              [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                          }];
```

Answer (score 1):

It opens the facebook seesion and optionally shows the login ux

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email",
                            @"user_likes",
                            nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copying @Stas Zhukovskiy answer in comments to the answer box:

**there is a mismatch in the docs tutorial and the sample. You should use - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI; instead. – [Stas Zhukovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573938/stas-zhukovskiy)**

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Sharekit
It is very easy to implement and also supports other social networks.
[sharekit](http://www.getsharekit.com/)

[Share kit tutorial](http://getsharekit.com/tutorial/facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Some code of line is missing in App Delegate.Just check that one.after that u will check open session and closed session on the time of calling method for Facebook.