# Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 Login Tutorial Issue with FBSession

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I am currently trying to put together an app - with the foundation of it being (hopefully) built on the Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 tutorial.

The tutorial I am following is located at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

I have found there to be a few changes throughout the various SDK versions from Facebook when it comes to the final release.

However I do have one final issue before the code will compile:

"No known class method for selector 'sessionOpenWithPermissions:completionHandler:'"

This error refers to the following code:

```
- (void)openSession
{
    [FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions:nil completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];    
}
```

When looking at the FBSession.h file in Xcode there is no mention of `sessionOpenWithPermissions`.

Can anyone please help me with regard to this? I am new to Objective-C/Xcode and am learning via trial by fire.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, got my code working with the below change.

```
//REPLACE
[FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions:nil
                    completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                    }];

//WITH
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:nil
                               allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                              [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                          }];
```

If you alt click on the method you'll get more info on the parameters to pass.
[openActiveSessionWithPermissions options](http://postimage.org/image/z88nkt7xd/)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help guys. One follow-up question though. The code change you suggest works - I found it in the Scrumptious example now that I know what I'm looking for but an error occurs when I click on the login button on the main page of the app. The error says "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT" on the "return" statement in the following code in main.m:


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "MMAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, 

NSStringFromClass([MMAppDelegate class]));

    }
}

Comment: Sorry for the lack of formatting but I don't know how to format code blocks in comments :S

Comment: Maybe check that all the method linked to your button are available, It happened to me before when playing around I deleted or renamed an IBAction in the code but still had it linked on the button in the xib or post your full code.

Comment: `openActiveSessionWithPermissions` is depreciated. Quoting from SDK Guide: If your app previously used v3.0 of the SDK, you will need to remove usage of `openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:` and replace it with `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:` (or even more simply, `openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation has a bug. According the API Change log, that class method as been replaced.

> FBSession class method sessionOpenWithPermissions:completionHandler: has been removed, instead use the new openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler: class method.

[API Change log URL](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/change-log-3.x/)

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance but what would the correct code be?

Comment: You would replace the openSession method in the AppDelegate with one similar to:`code`-(void)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI

Comment: You will also update all calls to the method accordingly. Check out the finished Scrumptious example project as it was updated with the new class method implementation.