# Unable to launch facebook using iPhone Apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, xcode4

I am integrating facebook to my iphone application. for that I downloaded `FacebookSDK` and included it into my project.

I dont know where I went wrong, as I got below error when I lauch facebook through my apps

> +[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a680c 2012-08-14 15:13:37.894
>   RightHand[11822:15803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FBSession
>   openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class **strong text**

Can anyone help me out in solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to put some code so that we can get to know what went wrong? But now from the error it is possible that you have wrong class or iVar which is calling the function and it is not been defined in that class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 Login Tutorial Issue with FBSession](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925987/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-login-tutorial-issue-with-fbsession)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that what framework you add into your project !

is "FacebookSDK.framework"

not "FBiOSSDK.framework"