# Facebook login on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to allow users to login to my app, through Facebook.  I am following this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

I have followed all of the steps including the step named "Getting started with the Facebook sdk for iOS".

When I copy and paste the following method, I get an error here:

```
 return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
```

Here is the method I copied and pasted.

```
    - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {

NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"read_stream",
                        nil];

return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                         state:state
                                                         error:error];
                                 }];
    }
```

The error says this: "No known class method for selector 'openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:'"

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
Let me know if you'd like to see some more of my code to figure the problem out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 Login Tutorial Issue with FBSession](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925987/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-login-tutorial-issue-with-fbsession)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update you facebook sdk to the latest one, and follow Scrumptious example.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt this is gonna solve your problem, but it's worth a shot. NSError usually takes an ampersand ("&") before getting passed as an argument. So write it as `error:&error` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing mLamaa answer, take a look on Facebook Upgrade Guide and follow these 2 steps:

1- Update facebook SDK

2- Replace the openActiveSessionWithPermissions function to openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions

Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading/

*Upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1*

"Therefore, if your app previously used v3.0 of the SDK, you will need to **remove usage of openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler: and replace it with openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler**: (or even more simply, openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI)."